# How to validate 2 separated string with Validator in laravel 6?

Tags: validation, laravel-blade, laravel-validation

I would like to make a validation for the input string using Laravel 6 with the input condition as below.

```
userNo = "5031234567"  => Len = 10 digits and must start with 503.
```

I tried to validate userNo with Laravel Validator as below and the result = Passed.

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
   'userNo' => 'required|regex:/^(\b[503])([0-9]{9})$/'
]);
```

Above was normal flow before but now I have a new rule to have the second userNo format as below condition.

```
userNo = "504123456"  => Len = 9 digits and must start with 504.
```

I would to validate the new rule.

I tried to combine the above Strings of `userNo` into the below validation but error 500.

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
   'userNo' => 'required|regex:/^(\b[503|504])([0-9]{9})$/'
]);
```

Now, I tried separating with the if...else.. statement to validate with the below code and it throws "The userNo format is invalid."

```
if(ubstr($data["telephone"],0,3) == '504')
{
   $validator = Validator::make($data, [
      'userNo' => 'required|regex:/^(\b[504])([0-9]{9})$/'
   ]);
} else
{
   $validator = Validator::make($data, [
      'userNo' => 'required|regex:/^(\b[503])([0-9]{9})$/'
   ]);
}
```

This is the simple return or response if validation fails.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json([
     'ResultCode' => 4005,
      'Detail' => $validator->errors()
   ], 401);
}
```

Could anyone have a suggestion to handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'userNo' => [
        'required',
        'regex:/^(503|504)[0-9]{9}$/'
    ]
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'ResultCode' => 4005,
        'Detail' => $validator->errors()
    ], 401);
}
```

This will work fine

Comment: It doesn't work for me throw "The user no format is invalid."

Comment: 'regex:/^(503\d{7}|504\d{8})$/' try this and let me know

Comment: It works with 'regex:/^(503\d{7}|504\d{6})$/'